# Pygame mixer playing sounds when I don't want it to

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, mixer

I'm trying to make this program that uses the keyboard, or a gh guitar with joytokey. I'm trying to set the "fret" variable when you push 1,2,3,4, or 5. And play the correct sound when you press k or l. But when I press 1,2,3,4, or 5, it plays the sound.
Heres the important bit of the code:

```
def playFret(fret):
    if fret == 1:
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(eguitargreen)
    if fret == 2:
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(eguitarred)
    if fret == 3:
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(eguitaryellow)
    if fret == 4:
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(eguitarblue)
    if fret == 5:
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(eguitarorange)


while jamtime:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
              jamtime = False 
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    
        
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                jamtime = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                fret = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_2:
                fret = 2
            if event.key == pygame.K_3:
                fret = 3
            if event.key == pygame.K_4:
                fret = 4
            if event.key == pygame.K_5:
                fret = 5
                
            if event.key == pygame.K_r or pygame.K_l:
                playFret(fret)
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how conditions work. `if event.key == pygame.K_r or pygame.K_l:` is the same as `if event.key == pygame.K_r: if pygame.K_l:`. The second condition will always be true as everything that's not zero or empty is true. You probably want something as explained in [BWallDev's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64920664/6486738) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your k and l key check to:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_r or event.key == pygame.K_l:
    playFret(fret)
```

The way your if statement works, isn't how you expect it to work. For example, what do you think the following code will print:

```
num = 7

if num == 4 or 5:
  print("yup")
else:
  print("nope")
```

Output:

```
yup
```